# Android how to change only part of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm learning Android development and don't fully understand how activities link together.

For example if I want a static settingbar/navbar at the top and change everything below that depending on the desired screen from the user.

Do I basically recreate the navbar for each screen? Or is there a way to keep the bar up and only change the stuff below it?

Comment: by settingbar/navbar, do you mean this: http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html

Comment: i see your mean. that is possible, you can keep navbar on top for activity and only change content of below layout part. I suggesst you use fragment as content container

Comment: @Da-JinC No, just in general apps with static bars up top where you can access various pages of the app via UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think more efficient approach would be using fragments. In this approach you can have a single activity and and a fragmenyt container such as FrameLayout. You can use the toolbar in the activity and only changing the fragment when the content is to changed. See [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) for understanding how fragments work. This way you don't have to include the toolbar in each and every xml files and all the controls of the toolbar are centered on the same activity

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want, actually. There is no specific rule.

It is possible to change only views below your `ActionBar`, as well as it is possible for you to recreate everything. I guess it depends on your application, but I would definetly not recommend working with a *single* Activity, especially for beginners. Code can get really messy and unmaintainable.

Basically, if you are working with multiple activities, you'll have multiple layout `xml` files. So, if you want the `ActionBar` to remain the same, you can create a e.g. `app_bar_layout.xml` file with its code, and just [**`include`**](http://developer.android.com/intl/en/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) that throughout your code, in other XML files.

Comment: Do I build each layout file as if they were layers in Photoshop? Stack them over each other in the code?

Comment: You should read about layouts in Android first, as it seems you have no idea of how it works. Take a look at the docs (http://developer.android.com/intl/en/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) . Layouts are basically XML files where you "code its design".

Comment: I know that (I've made a few apps already) but don't know how to do more complex things. I don't know how to update "part" of a screen. I only know how to bring about entirely new layouts with startactivity(intent)

Comment: Well it varies from situation to situation. You can do it in many ways. For example, using `ViewPager`s  to store multiple tabs; using a `LayoutInflater` to inflate a previous defined `xml` into your layout; messing with `ViewGroup` views such as `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`s visibility; setting `ListView` adapters dynamically  and updating it; creating Layouts programatically passing the context as parameter; etc. It really depends on the situation